# Resize bar button item in iOS 11 without using auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibarbuttonitem, ios11

I have an old app that I wrote as a beginner that I'd like to update for iOS 11. The app is written in Objective-C and does not use auto layout.

This is how the bar button items in the navigation bar should look (and how they do look in iOS 10):

### [image: iOS 10]

However, in iOS 11 the buttons look like this:

[image]

---

How do I resize the buttons so they look like they did in iOS 10 without using auto layout? (My project didn't use auto layout back then.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Override intrinsic content size and add padding.

Comment: How do you set up the NavigationBar and what kind of style is this?

Comment: @Brandon: Could you provide some more detailed instructions? I'm still a beginner.

Comment: @grethi: I used [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0)] as the background image for the bar button item.

Comment: @James Is it a customView UIBarButtonItem or one with a simple title? May you offer some source code?

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 11, if you want a `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom size, you're going to have to set its `widthAnchor` and `heightAnchor` properties. If you were manually setting the frame before, make sure you still do that so your buttons don't disappear.

Your code might look something like:

```
/* setting 1) frame, 2) widthAnchor, and 3) heightAnchor because iOS 11 
needs the latter two, and lower versions need the frame */

/* 1) */
[self.nextButton setFrame:(CGRect){
    .size = nextButton_size
}];

/* 2) */
[self.nextButton.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:nextButton_size.width].active = YES;

/* 3) */
[self.nextButton.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:nextButton_size.height].active = YES;

UIBarButtonItem* const nextBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.nextButton];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nextBarButton];
```